# linux shell скрипт: скопировать последние модифицированные файлы

Tags: linux, shell, sh

Я скачиваю файлы командой `wget` по `crontab` с ftp и нужно копировать 10 последних измененных файлов в другой каталог, т.к. меня интересуют только они, а оставлять весь набор xml файлов размером в ~1Гб будет затратно по времени для обработки.

Также учитываю, что wget должен завершиться, а уже потом выполняться копирование, т.е. последовательное выполнение команд консольного скрипта.

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -конфигурация ;
cp ...
```

Пожалуйста, помогите сконфигурировать команду копирования в моем случае.

Comment: Не понял проблемы. Вам надо скачать файлы себе, сверить их (способов сравнить много) с целевыми и скопировать куда надо, так? А что именно не получается?

Comment: Фактически сейчас я докачиваю файлы с ftp, т.к. каталог пополняется. Поэтому докачанные нужно скопировать в другую директорию и потом как-то обработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если *http*-сервер отдаёт правильный заголовок `last-modified`, то программа *wget* устанавливает время модификации файла, указанное в таком заголовке.

получить список файлов в текущем каталоге, отсортированный по времени модификации, можно, например, с помощью программы `ls` с опцией `-t`:

```
$ ls -t *
```

более новые файлы будут присутствовать выше более старых.

отобрать нужное количество строк от начала списка можно, например, программой `head`, указав количество с помощью опции `-n количество`:

```
$ ls -t * | head -n количество
```

результат можно подставить в качестве набора первых аргументов программе `cp` (последним аргументом должен быть каталог, куда будут скопированы эти файлы):

```
$ cp $(ls -t * | head -n количество) /куда/копировать/
```

но если предполагается наличие в именах файлов спец-символов (например, пробел), то эту команду придётся значительно усложнить, воспользовавшись, к примеру, возможностями программы *xargs*:

```
$ ls -t * | head -n количество | xargs -I'{}' -d '\n' cp '{}' /куда/копировать
```

---

подробности:

- `$ man ls`
- `$ man head`
- `$ man cp`
- `$ man xargs`